# Mode of each digit in binary strings of a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to find the mode value of each digit in binary strings of a pandas column.  Suppose I have the following data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'categories':['A','B','C'],'values':['001','110','111']})
```

so my data look like this

```
categories    values
A             001
B             110
C             111
```

If we consider the column "values" at the first digit (0, 1, 1) of A, B, and C respectively, the mode value is 1.  If we do the same for other digits, my expected output should be 111.

I can find a mode value of a particular column.  If I split each bit into a new column and find the mode value.  I could get the expected output by concatenation later.  However, when the data has much more columns of binary strings, I'm not sure whether this method still be a good way to do.  I'm looking for the more elegant method do this.  May I have your suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `apply` with `Series` and `list` for convert `digits` to columns and then [`mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html):

```
print (df['values'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x))))
   0  1  2
0  0  0  1
1  1  1  0
2  1  1  1

df1 = df['values'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x))).mode()
print (df1)
   0  1  2
0  1  1  1
```

Last select row, create `list` and `join`:

```
print (''.join(df1.iloc[0].tolist()))
111
```

Another possible solution with `list comprehension`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([list(x) for x in df['values']])
print (df)
   0  1  2
0  0  0  1
1  1  1  0
2  1  1  1
```

If output is `DataFrame` is possible use `apply` `join`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'categories':['A','B','C', 'D'],'values':['001','110','111', '000']})
print (df)
  categories values
0          A    001
1          B    110
2          C    111
3          D    000

print (pd.DataFrame([list(x) for x in df['values']]).mode())
   0  1  2
0  0  0  0
1  1  1  1

df1 = pd.DataFrame([list(x) for x in df['values']]).mode().apply(''.join, axis=1)
print (df1)
0    000
1    111
dtype: object
```